# jQuery right textbox value are not getting on submitdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jeditable, owl-carousel-2

I am using two jQuery plugin for my project.

1. [Owl Carusel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/)
2. [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html)

In my example, I have four image slides and every image slider I have added comment section for image. For comment I have used `Jeditable` plugin for inline commenting.

### Here is my HTML part:

```
<div id="dino-example" class="dino-carousel">
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <h1>
       Slide 1
      </h1>
            <p>
                Ut laborum. Nisi ipsum natus laborum ea nemo distinctio. Laborum aspernatur sed sit, et quod illum.
            </p>
            <p class="editable_textarea" id="paragraph_1">click here to edit text content</p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" class="inv" value="1">
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h1>
      Slide 2
      </h1>
        <p>
            Consequat. Recusandae. Lorem a iure alias officia aut officiis repellendus. Aliquid quasi ad voluptate modi non est veniam, quo.
        </p>
        <p class="editable_textarea" id="paragraph_1">click here to edit text content</p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="inv" value="2">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h1>
      Slide 3
      </h1>
        <p>
            Tempore, consequuntur est occaecat doloribus qui dignissimos voluptatem eius voluptatem ea iusto.
        </p>
        <p class="editable_textarea" id="paragraph_1">click here to edit text content</p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="inv" value="3">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h1>
      Slide 4
      </h1>
        <p>
            Sit dolor ut culpa, deserunt placeat, deleniti minus ut magna fugit, rerum aliquid est magni aliqua. Qui unde.
        </p>
        <p class="editable_textarea" id="paragraph_1">click here to edit text content</p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="inv" value="4">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div>

</div>
```

### jQuery part:

```
var currentIndex = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dino-example").owlCarousel({
        items: 5,
        singleItem: true,
        afterMove: function() {
            currentIndex = this.currentItem;
        }
    });
});

$(".editable_textarea").editable("http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/php/save.php", {
    indicator: "",
    type: 'textarea',
    submitdata: {
        projectidx: $("#dino-example .inv").val()
    },
    select: true,
    submit: 'OK',
    cancel: 'cancel',
    cssclass: "editable"
});
```

Now problem is that, I am not able pass `textbox` value with `editable` on ajax when submit button is clicked. I am getting first slide textbox value on every slides which not valid.

```
submitdata: {
    projectidx: $("#dino-example .inv").val()
},
```

Not getting on `$("#dino-example .inv").val()` textbox value, If I am on second slide.

Any idea how to pass textbox value?

Here is my example code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f43waf7j/3/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `submitdata`by this snippet:

```
$(".editable_textarea").editable("http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/php/save.php", {
  // ...
  submitdata: function(){ 
     return { projectidx: $(".inv").eq(currentIndex).val() };
  },
  // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is how you're grabbing the value of the `.inv` input. When you call:

```
$("#dino-example .inv").val()
```

jQuery is selecting all 4 input elements on the page, as there are 4 input elements on the page matching the `$("#dino-example .inv")` selector. You can see this in action by running `$("#dino-example .inv")` in your console:

```
> $("#dino-example .inv")
< [<input type=​"text" class=​"inv" value=​"1">​, <input type=​"text" class=​"inv" value=​"2">​, <input type=​"text" class=​"inv" value=​"3">​, <input type=​"text" class=​"inv" value=​"4">​]
```

Calling `.val()` on the selector returns the value for the first matched element, which is the first input element on the page.

To grab the 2nd, 3rd or 4th input element's value you'll need to use something like `.eq()` ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)). Chaining `.eq(1)` to your selector will select the 2nd element from the set of matched elements. Likewise, `.eq(2)` to your selector will select the 2nd element from the set of matched elements

For example. to grab the value of the input from the 2nd slide use:

```
$("#dino-example .inv").eq(1).val()
```

Now, in your case you want to grab the value of the input corresponding to the current slide. That is, when the user clicks OK on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th slides you want to grab the value of the `.inv` input associated with that slide.

To do that you can chain several selectors together with the `this` selector to grab each value based on the current slide.

```
$(this).next('p').children('.inv').val()
```

For each slide `$(this)` refers to the `editable` element. Chaining `.next('p').children('.inv')` selects the `.inv` input on the same slide.

Here's [your JSFiddle with an alert displaying the correct input value](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/qbdy6pn1/1/).

Comment: But I don't know how to pass slider textbox value to here `submitdata: {
    projectidx: $("#dino-example .inv").val()
},`.

Comment: Ah, you need to grab the input corresponding to the current slide. You can use `$(this).next('p').children('.inv').val()` to do that. This selector works by starting at `editable` element, moving to the next `p` element, then down to the `.inv` input to grab it's value.